# sorting Japanese characters using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, localization

I have the following line to sort a list of items by name:

```
let nameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "item.itemName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare))
```

This works fine for English names.  But with Japanese it sorts the Hiragana, Katakana and Kanji separately rather than intertwined.  I noticed the iOS contacts app sorts correctly and does not divide the three separate scripts.  Wondering how to achieve this?

Comment: Try the three different `localizedxxxCompare` methods.

Comment: Was just trying that now based on what rmaddy said. Will keep trying. Must be a way for kanji to work as well judging by the contacts app. Thx.

Comment: I suspect so. But I guess this is an issue that has been around as long as the iPhone has supported Japanese language so hopefully there is a simple solution lurking underneath

Comment: I believe the Contacts app uses the `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` class to sort and section data. That may be worth looking into.

Comment: That’s also the way we enter the items. First in hiragana then change to kanji. I’ll look into the UILocalizedIndexedCollation class. Thx very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `localizedCompare` or `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` to solve the hiragana v katakana sorting issue, but not the kanji issue.

You compare this to the Contacts app: Unfortunately, Contacts actually [captures what you enter phonetically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eacYw.jpg), storing the furigana in a separate `phoneticFamilyName` (e.g., Tanaka as タナカ), whereas the final kanji (e.g., 田中) is stored in `familyName`, for example. It does this because once the input is translated to kanji, all readings are mapped to a single unicode sequence. E.g. whether you enter 中 via either チュウ or なか (depending up what word you enter it in), the resulting 中 character is still just unicode 0x4e2d. You need to save the phonetic spelling in a separate field if you want know how you got to that character.

Bottom line, to ask the sorting algorithm to figure out what the furigana for some random sequence of kanji is a non-trivial problem, because it has no way of knowing which *on yomi* or *kun yomi* or *nanori* applies for any given kanji. This is why the Contacts app stores this in a separate field. There are [`CFStringTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542411-cfstringtransform) transforms between kana and romaji, but not for kanji.

It certainly seems theoretically possible to do some natural language processing and/or dictionary parsing of the string, but that strikes me as fairly computationally intensive and probably not practical to try to do that just-in-time within a sorting routine. I would suggest storing the furigana in a separate field like the Contacts framework does.